# CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL return nill value

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics

I am developing a MacOS app for to edit metadata of image. For this purpose, I use  `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL` function for to create destination to the file located in 'Documents' or 'Desktop' but it returns `nil` value. I checked paremeters of the function (URL and file type) several times but can not find reason of the issue.

### Here is the code

```
@IBAction func browseFile(_ sender: AnyObject) {   
    let dialog = NSOpenPanel()
    dialog.title                   = "Choose a .txt file"
    dialog.showsResizeIndicator    = true
    dialog.showsHiddenFiles        = false
    dialog.canChooseDirectories    = true
    dialog.canCreateDirectories    = true
    dialog.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    dialog.allowedFileTypes        = nil
    if dialog.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {
        let result = dialog.url // Pathname of the file
        if result != nil {
            let path = result!.path
            filename_field.stringValue = path
            let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(result as! CFURL, nil)
            let type = CGImageSourceGetType(imageSource!)
            let uurl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        // here I am trying to create a destination but it returns nil
            var imageDest: CGImageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(uurl, type!, 1, nil)!
        }
    } else {
        // User clicked on "Cancel"
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you don't convert to a path and back?

Comment: @Willeke, unfortunately it does not work. An interesting side is that CGImageSourceCreateWithURL works with the same URL. I have tried with existed and non-existed file URLs but there is not any result.

Comment: Do you have permission to write at `uurl`?